# How to create a temporary 2D variable for cuda kernel

Tags: multidimensional-array, cuda, global-variables

My `Ix` and `Iy` declared in the CUDA global kernel will cause illegal memory access encounters due to unknown reasons. This is the code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Cuda
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"


#define CHECK_FINAL_RESULT
//#define CHECK_LOADING_DATA
using namespace std;
const int TSIZEX = 32;
const int TSIZEY = 256;
const int ft_size = 1;

// Mathematical algorithms
#define isl_min(x,y)        ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))         // compare value x is lesser than y, if correct use x, if wrong use y
#define isl_max(x,y)        ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))         // comapre value x is larger than y, if correct use y, if wrong use x

__device__ float cudafilter2sq(float A[16][34], float B[34][258], int i, int j);
__global__ void cudapipeline_harris(int  C, int  R, float* img, float* harris);

__device__ float cudafilter2sq(float A[34][258], float B[34][258], int i, int j) {

    return (A[i - 1][j - 1] * B[i - 1][j - 1] +
        A[i - 1][j] * B[i - 1][j] +
        A[i - 1][j + 1] * B[i - 1][j + 1] +
        A[i][j - 1] * B[i][j - 1] +
        A[i][j] * B[i][j] +
        A[i][j + 1] * B[i][j + 1] +
        A[i + 1][j - 1] * B[i + 1][j - 1] +
        A[i + 1][j] * B[i + 1][j] +
        A[i + 1][j + 1] * B[i + 1][j + 1]);
}



__global__ void cudapipeline_harris(int  C, int  R, float* img, float* harris) {

    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int idy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int idz = threadIdx.z + blockIdx.z * blockDim.z;

    float Ix[TSIZEX + 2 * ft_size][TSIZEY + 2 * ft_size];
    float Iy[TSIZEX + 2 * ft_size][TSIZEY + 2 * ft_size];

    for (int Ti = idx; Ti < (float)(R / TSIZEX); Ti += gridDim.x * blockDim.x)
    //if (Ti < (R / TSIZEX))
    {
        //for (int Tj = 0; Tj <= (float)(C / TSIZEY); Tj++)
        for (int Tj = idy; Tj < (float)(C/ TSIZEY); Tj += gridDim.y * blockDim.y)
        {
            int bot0, top0, right0, left0;
            int height, width;

            bot0 = isl_min(isl_max(Ti * TSIZEX, ft_size), R - ft_size);
            top0 = isl_min((Ti + 1) * TSIZEX, R - ft_size);
            left0 = isl_min(isl_max(Tj * TSIZEY, ft_size), C - ft_size);
            right0 = isl_min((Tj + 1) * TSIZEY, C - ft_size);

            width = right0 - left0;
            height = top0 - bot0;


            for (int i = bot0; i <= top0; i++)
            {
                for (int j = left0; j <= right0; j++)
                {
                    //printf("Ix : %d ", i - bot0);
                    Ix[i - bot0][j - left0] = img[(i - 1) * C + j - 1] * (-0.0833333333333f) +
                        img[(i + 1) * C + j - 1] * 0.0833333333333f +
                        img[(i + 1) * C + j] * 0.166666666667f +
                        img[(i - 1) * C + j] * -0.166666666667f +
                        img[(i - 1) * C + j + 1] * -0.0833333333333f +
                        img[(i + 1) * C + j + 1] * 0.0833333333333f;

                    Iy[i - bot0][j - left0] = img[(i - 1) * C + j - 1] * (-0.0833333333333f) +
                        img[(i - 1) * C + j + 1] * 0.0833333333333f +
                        img[i * C + j - 1] * -0.166666666667f +
                        img[i * C + j + 1] * 0.166666666667f +
                        img[(i + 1) * C + j - 1] * -0.0833333333333f +
                        img[(i + 1) * C + j + 1] * 0.0833333333333f;

                }
            }

           // for (int i = idy + bot0;i < (float)top0; i += gridDim.y * blockDim.y)
            for (int i = bot0; i < top0; i++)
            {
                for (int j = left0; j < right0; j++)
                {
                    int newI = i - bot0;
                    int newJ = j - left0;

                    harris[((i)*C + (j))] = cudafilter2sq(Ix, Ix, newI, newJ) * cudafilter2sq(Iy, Iy, newI, newJ) -
                        cudafilter2sq(Ix, Iy, newI, newJ) * cudafilter2sq(Ix, Iy, newI, newJ) -
                        (0.04f * (cudafilter2sq(Ix, Ix, newI, newJ) + cudafilter2sq(Iy, Iy, newI, newJ))) *
                        (cudafilter2sq(Ix, Ix, newI, newJ) + cudafilter2sq(Iy, Iy, newI, newJ));
                }
            }

        }
    }


}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, j, run;                // looping variables
    int R, C, nruns;              // height, width and number of loops runs
    double begin, end;            // each loop start time and end time
    double init, finish;          // total loop start time and end time
    double stime, avgt;           // time used and total avgt time
    cv::Mat image, loaded_data;
    cv::Scalar sc;
    cv::Size size;

    float* t_res;
    float* t_data;

    // Might be unused depending on preprocessor macro definitions
    (void)t_res;
    (void)t_data;
    (void)loaded_data;

    float* data;
    float* res;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Does not set the NRuns and image needed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    image = cv::imread(argv[1], 1);   // read image from command line argument [1]

    if (!image.data)
    {
        printf("No image data ! Are you sure %s is an image ?\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert image input to grayscale floating point
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    size = image.size();
    C = size.width;
    R = size.height;

    printf("Values settings :\n");
    printf("-------------------\n");
    printf("Image Used : %s [%i, %i] \n", argv[1], R, C);

    res = (float*)calloc(R * C, sizeof(*res));

    if (res == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while allocating result table of size %ld B\n",
            (sizeof(*res) * C * R));
        return -1;
    }

    data = (float*)malloc(R * C * sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i < R; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            sc = image.at<uchar>(i, j);
            data[i * C + j] = (float)sc.val[0] / 255;
        }
    }

    // Parallel Running Test
    printf("\n\n-----------------------------------\n");
    printf("Cuda\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    res = (float*)calloc(R * C, sizeof(*res));                // reset resources value

    dim3 grid(2,2,2);
    dim3 block(16,16,1);

    // Data required to pass to device
    float* img, * harris;

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&img, R * C * sizeof(*img));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&harris, R * C * sizeof(*harris));


    cudaMemcpy(img, data, C * R * sizeof(*data), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   // pass image value to the GPU

    cudaEventRecord(start);
    cudapipeline_harris << < grid, block >> > (C, R, img, harris);
    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float milliseconds = 0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
    //cudapipeline_harris << < 1, 8 >> > (C, R, img, harris);

   cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    cudaMemcpy(res, harris, C * R * sizeof(*harris), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA ERROR : %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("Total time   :  \t %f ms\n", milliseconds);


#ifdef CHECK_FINAL_RESULT
    // Serial Show input
    cv::namedWindow("Input", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::imshow("Input", image);
    image.release();
    // Parallel Show output
    cv::Mat imres = cv::Mat(R, C, CV_32F, res);
    cv::namedWindow("Parallel Output", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::imshow("Parallel Output", imres * 65535.0);
    imres.release();
#endif

    cudaFree(harris);
    cudaFree(img);

    free(data);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error shown:

```
CUDA ERROR : an illegal memory access was encountered

**CUDA ERROR : unspecified launch failure========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x000002d0 in C:/Users/Jiayih/source/repos/cuda/cuda/main.cu:383:cudafilter2sq(float[258]*, float[258]*, int, int)
=========     by thread (15,1,0) in block (0,0,1)
=========     Address 0x2c6f5fee774 is out of bounds
=========     Device Frame:C:/Users/Jiayih/source/repos/cuda/cuda/main.cu:453:cudapipeline_harris(int, int, float*, float*) (cudapipeline_harris(int, int, float*, float*) : 0x2130)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll [0x81dcd]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll [0x82167]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll [0x8686e]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0x11473a) [0x3322ba]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll [0x176ea9]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0xe97c2) [0x307342]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll [0x361bd]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll [0x365e1]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll [0x368c4]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamui.inf_amd64_544551ddc9ce8575\nvcuda64.dll (cuLaunchKernel + 0x234) [0x20d954]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin\cudart64_110.dll [0x8dba]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin\cudart64_110.dll [0x8c66]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin\cudart64_110.dll (cudaLaunchKernel + 0x1c4) [0x29024]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Jiayih\source\repos\cuda\x64\Debug\cuda.exe (main + 0x1f) [0x516f]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Jiayih\source\repos\cuda\x64\Debug\cuda.exe (__device_stub__Z19cudapipeline_harrisiiPfS_ + 0x22e) [0x4fbe]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Jiayih\source\repos\cuda\x64\Debug\cuda.exe (cudapipeline_harris + 0x41) [0x44c1]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Jiayih\source\repos\cuda\x64\Debug\cuda.exe (main + 0x577) [0x4a47]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Jiayih\source\repos\cuda\x64\Debug\cuda.exe (invoke_main + 0x39) [0xfa79]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Jiayih\source\repos\cuda\x64\Debug\cuda.exe (__scrt_common_main_seh + 0x12e) [0xf95e]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Jiayih\source\repos\cuda\x64\Debug\cuda.exe (__scrt_common_main + 0xe) [0xf81e]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Jiayih\source\repos\cuda\x64\Debug\cuda.exe (mainCRTStartup + 0x9) [0xfb09]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x14) [0x17bd4]
=========     Host Frame:C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21) [0x6ce51]
=========**
```

Comment: "My Ix and Iy declared in the Cuda global kernel will cause illegal memory access encounter".  The simple fact that you have these arrays declared per-thread does not mean that you will automatically run into an illegal memory access error.  [Here](https://pastebin.com/sQYLAcHU) is proof.  Therefore more details are needed.  For a question like this, you are expected to provide a [mcve], see item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) note use of the word "must".

Comment: @RobertCrovella hi, thanks for giving reply, i am just new to cuda  and i hope to seek for the solution of my code, do you mind to share yr email to me, so that i can send the complete source code with you?

Comment: Sorry, that's not how stack overflow works.  Please read the information I have already given you.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for the information, i have try to update the questions. Thanks

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for your solution, the error is due to the condition to put the variable newI > 0 && newJ > 0

Comment: But i have the same code in openMP and MPI, but the code work pretty fine, it a bit weird haha. Anyway, i really appreciate your help

Comment: It is illegal indexing in C or C++.  Just because it happens to work somewhere doesn't mean that it is proper coding.  It is a coding defect.  A bug in your code.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the reason you are getting this level of detailed error reporting from CUDA (`Invalid global read...`) is that you have the [memory checker functionality](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Use_Memory_Checker.htm) in Nsight Visual Studio edition turned **on**. The memory checker behaves, for device code, something like the tool valgrind does for host code. If you have the same defect (indexing into arrays negatively) in your other codes, and run them under valgrind, you might also get an error report

Comment: @RobertCrovella hi, can i have a extra question to ask you, because the cuda code cannot increase the efficiency of the serial code, i am wondering why?

Comment: You're making various mistakes from a code design perspective.  It's fairly evident that your kernel has no use for the z dimension, but your grid is structured to launch a depth of 2 blocks in z.  This makes no sense whatsoever, and is doubling the work the GPU is doing, for no purpose.  Also, if we leave aside the useless doubling of work in z, you are launching a total of 2*16*2*16 threads, i.e. 1024 threads total.  This is not enough to saturate any but the tiniest of GPUs. It's unlikely this will get good efficiency on any larger GPU.

Comment: That's a few quick observations.  I'm sorry, I won't be able to cover a full tutorial on CUDA programming, or good CUDA program design, in the space of these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug process here is fairly straightforward. Your CUDA error output is pointing to an out-of-range access error in `cudafilter2sq` as indicated here:

```
Invalid global read of size 4 ========= at ...cuda/main.cu:383:cudafilter2sq
... Address ... is out of bounds
```

Looking at `cudafilter2sq`, ask yourself the question "how could one of those accesses be out of range?" Since that function is fairly simple, the answer is, "if one of the indexes ( computed from `i` or `j`) is out of range for `A`/`Ix` or `B`/`Iy`. Then you just test those computed indexes against the known possible ranges (0-33, 0-257).

It should be quite evident that `cudafilter2sq` requires an `i` value greater than 0, otherwise `i-1` will index out of range. But you are not satisfying this requirement. Add:

```
 #include <assert.h>
```

and then add:

```
 assert(i > 0);
```

to the very beginning of `cudafilter2sq`. Then run your code with the memory checking feature enabled (as you are already doing). You will hit these device asserts, indicating you are indexing out-of-range. You have the same problem with `j`.

When I add the following code to the beginning of `cudafilter2sq`:

```
if (i < 1) i = 1;  if (j < 1) j = 1;
```

your code runs without error for me. It should be fairly evident that if your `cudapipeline_harris` kernel for-loop starts with:

```
 ...int i = bot0;...
```

then:

```
 int newI = i - bot0;
```

can produce a zero value for `newI` (and likewise for `newJ`).  So this seems to be the "source" of the indexing problem.  I assume you can fix it from here.

Also, note that your forward declaration for `cudafilter2sq`:

```
__device__ float cudafilter2sq(float A[16][34], float B[34][258], int i, int j);
```

doesn't match the definition

```
__device__ float cudafilter2sq(float A[34][258], float B[34][258], int i, int j)
```